# Animate button in React on state change

Tags: reactjs, typescript, css-transitions

Im trying to do a button that animate label when something happens (onclick, http success/error). But I can't figure out how to apply the classes and find an elegant way to handle it via component state.

When clicking the button it transition from `IDLE` to `BUSY` state. When promise resolves (`SUCCESS`) or rejects (`FAILURE`). After 3 secs it resets back to `IDLE`.

I'm trying to switch className according to state. But it's not working and I can't figure out how to do it properly. I'm not sure if (and how) I should use `react-transition-group` plugin to do this smoothly, as the component is not mounted/unmounted conditionally.

Maybe I should use css animation instead of css transition. Would this be a better approach?

live example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/yjl5o5vr4v

this is my code:

**SubmitButton.tsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { IconProp } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import classNames from 'classnames'
import './SubmitButton.css'

// flag to switch whether dummy request should succeed or fail
let workSuccess = true

interface IProps {}
interface IState {
  status: 'IDLE' | 'BUSY' | 'SUCCESS' | 'FAILURE'
  label: string
  icon?: IconProp
}

const initialState: IState = {
  status: 'IDLE',
  label: 'Click',
  icon: undefined,
}

class SubmitButton extends React.PureComponent<IProps, IState> {
  public state: IState = { ...initialState }
  public render() {
    const { label, icon, status } = this.state

    return (
      <button className="SubmitButton" onClick={this.handleClick}>
        <span
          className={classNames({
            'animation--after': status === 'BUSY',
            'animation--before': status === 'SUCCESS' || status === 'FAILURE',
            ['animation']: status === 'IDLE',
          })}
        >
          {icon && (
            <FontAwesomeIcon className="SubmitButton__icon" icon={icon} />
          )}
          {label}
        </span>
      </button>
    )
  }

  private handleClick = async (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    const { status } = this.state
    if (status === 'IDLE') {
      // animation: 'roll up' (out of view)

      // animation: reset position
      this.setState({
        label: 'Loading...',
        icon: 'spinner',
        status: 'BUSY',
      })

      // animation: 'roll up' (into view)

      try {
        const response = await this.doWork()
        // animation: 'roll up' (out of view)

        if (response) {
          // animation: reset position
          this.setState({
            label: 'OK',
            icon: 'check',
            status: 'SUCCESS',
          })
          // animation: 'roll up' (into view)
        }
      } catch (err) {
        // animation: reset position
        this.setState({
          label: 'ERROR',
          icon: 'exclamation',
          status: 'FAILURE',
        })
        // animation: 'roll up' (into view)
      } finally {
        // animation: reset position
        this.setState({ ...initialState })
        // animation: 'roll up' (into view)
      }
    }
  }

  private doWork = () => {
    return new Promise<boolean>((resolve: any, reject: any) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (workSuccess) {
          resolve(true)
        } else {
          reject('An error happened...')
        }

        workSuccess = !workSuccess
      }, 3000)
    })
  }
}

export default SubmitButton
```

**SubmitButton.css**

```
.SubmitButton {
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 32px;
}

.SubmitButton__icon {
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.animation {
  display: inline-block;
  transition: transform 300ms ease-out;
  transform: translateY(0);
}
.animation--before {
  transition: transform 300ms ease-out;
  transform: translateY(50px);
}
.animation--after {
  transition: transform 300ms ease-out;
  transform: translateY(-50px);
}
```

Comment: you could use CSS animation, here's an example - https://codesandbox.io/s/x2mxr18moq

Comment: This is not what i want. Every time status changes i want the label to slide up and out and the new label to slide up and in.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the gif image instead of FontAwesome icon. please check below code.

currently I have used low quality gif for example purpose but you can load a good gif from your project.

```
 class SubmitButton extends React.PureComponent<IProps, IState> {
  public state: IState = { ...initialState };
  public render() {
    const { label, icon, status } = this.state;

    return (
      <>
        <button className="SubmitButton" onClick={this.handleClick}>
          <span
            className={classNames({
              "animation--after": status === "BUSY",
              "animation--before": status === "SUCCESS" || status === "FAILURE",
              ["animation"]: status === "IDLE"
            })}
          >
            {icon && (
              <img src="http://www.ajaxload.info/cache/FF/FF/FF/00/00/00/1-0.gif" />
            )}
            {label}
          </span>
        </button>
      </>
    );
  }
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/ry08jyr1rp)